# How to fetch the timestamp based value using aggregation - mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am having following sample

#### mongodb document

```
  {

  "request" : [
    {
        "bytesSent" : "6605",
        "bytesRecieved" : "1987",
        "currentVisit" : "1384766024",
        "lastVisit" : "1384766024"
    },
    {
        "bytesSent" : "6605",
        "bytesRecieved" : "1987",
        "currentVisit" : "1384766024",
        "lastVisit" : "1384766024"
    }
       ],
    uuid :"b90fb200-5031-11e3-9b59-2f102c87ef20-13decb4fb6fd1"
 }
```

I want to aggregate the uuid based on the `currentVisit`  and `lastVisit` in the `request` array in the above document.

I want to convert the normal query to aggregation using uuid.

```
db.collection.find({"request.currentVisit":{$gte:"1384766024",$lte:"1384766024"}});
```

Any help will be greatful.

Comment: What are you trying to do that isn't working? You say that you want to aggregate but you're not using aggregation.

Comment: @WiredPrairie. I was looking for aggregation query. Now i got the query just check the edit.

Comment: The right choice is to answer your own question. It makes it very clear there is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below Aggregation query is working great.

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$request"},{$match:{"request.currentVisit":{$gte:"1384766024",$lte:"1384766024"}}},{$group:{_id:"$uuid"}});
```

#### Steps

1. Unwind the request array to normal document.
2. Matching the timestamp fields using $match based on the `currentVisit` inside the `request` document.
3. Grouping the documents using the `uuid` field.

Answer (score -2):

request field is an array, so there's not request.currentVisit, try this:

```
{ request:{$elemMatch:{currentVisit:{$gte:"1384766024",$lte:"1384766024"}}} }
```

Comment: this return only the first occurrence. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/ "If multiple elements match the $elemMatch condition, the operator returns the first matching element in the array."

Comment: The element means the element in array "request" of the matched document. But I think you need to select out many documents right?

Comment: You can use `request.currentVisit` to find documents that match the specified condition. That syntax works for arrays as well as subdocuments.